# Looping through iam user arn's to pass to aws_lakeformation_permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-lake-formation

I am defining lake formation permissions and I wanted to loop through all user's that are part of the admin and security IAM Group and pass them in the principal section as follows :

```
resource "aws_lakeformation_permissions" "example" {
  for_each = data.aws_iam_users.users
  principal   = "A LIST OF IAM USER ARNS FROM ADMIN IAM GROUP"
  permissions = ["CREATE_TABLE", "ALTER", "DROP"]

  database {
    name       = aws_glue_catalog_database.example.name
    catalog_id = "110376042874"
  }
}
```

I have looked at the following documentation on terraform to make use of the data source but am not sure how to reference a specific IAM Group within this :

```
data "aws_iam_users" "users" {}
```

I understand I need to make use of for_each but not entirely sure of how to obtain the list of IAM User arns that are part of the IAM Group admin and security. Is it not possible to do this via the data source

```
data "aws_iam_users" "users" {}
```

I have tried to make use of this data source : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_users

Comment: How about: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_group?

Comment: @MarkoE- Could you provide an example of how I could use this data source to target a list of iam users as part of the admin iam group. That would be really helpful

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. The `principal` argument takes exactly one ARN, it cannot work with a list of ARNs. Additionally, I think it would be better to use an IAM role instead of a group.

Comment: @MarkoE - The problem is I have a list of IAM Groups and as part of lake formation only IAM users and IAM Roles can be used to provide permissions. Can I not loop through a list of IAM users as part of an IAM group in the principal section ?

Comment: You can loop through a list of users that belong to a group using `for_each` and assign a single user to a principal for each of the elements. Groups are not considered as real identities in IAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
data "aws_iam_group" "admin" {
  group_name = "admin"
}

data "aws_iam_group" "security" {
  group_name = "security"
}

resource "aws_lakeformation_permissions" "example" {
  for_each = { for usr in concat(data.aws_iam_group.admin.users, data.aws_iam_group.security.users): usr.user_name => usr.arn }
  principal   = each.value
  permissions = ["CREATE_TABLE", "ALTER", "DROP"]

  database {
    name       = aws_glue_catalog_database.example.name
    catalog_id = "110376042874"
  }
}
```

1. Use `aws_iam_group` instead of `aws_iam_users` because the latter cannot give you a list of users by group.
2. `for_each` can loop over a set of strings or a map. You have to use `{ for ... }` loop to transform `data.aws_iam_group.admin.users` list of objects into a map. More about it here - https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#result-types.

Comment: If I wanted to just reference the admin team , would it be as follows: 

for_each = { for usr in data.aws_iam_group.admin.users: usr.user_name => usr.arn } 

So for the key usr.user_name I want the value of usr.arn ? Is that correct the way I am understanding it

Comment: @arooz correct. Replace `concat(data.aws_iam_group.admin.users, data.aws_iam_group.security.users)` with just `data.aws_iam_group.admin.users`. The resulting map is user_name (each.key) => user_arn (each.value).

Comment: Thank you for that. Does the data source usually always return a list of objects usually OR does it depend what type of data source is being used ? @Anton

Comment: @arooz I'd say it's a list of objects most of the time, the return values usually have more than one attribute. If not sure, you can declare a temporary Terraform `output` with the value you want to inspect.